# How to properly install tailwind on a dockerized react app in a compose?

Tags: reactjs, docker, tailwind-css

I am currently working on a dockerized react app in one of the containers of a docker compose. I am using yarn as my project manager. I have followed the installation guide on tailwindcss.com, but it didn't work for me. There is no error showing in the log. It is just simply the classes in tailwind not working at all. I have put @tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities; in my index.css, but it seems that the @tailwind is "Cannot find declaration to go to". I have tried to use import instead of @tailwind, but it still doesn't work. The tailwindcss file is indeed in the node_modules file, but anything from tailwind is not usable for me. All my packages are working fine except tailwind and daisyui.

Here is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM node:16-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app

RUN yarn config set network-timeout 600000 -g

FROM base AS dev
CMD ["yarn", "dev"]

FROM base AS builder
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
COPY . .
RUN yarn build

FROM --platform=$TARGETPLATFORM nginx:1.19-alpine AS server
COPY ./etc/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder ./app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Here is my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "daisyui": "^3.9.3",
    "jssha": "^3.3.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-promise": "^0.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "tailwindcss build src/index.css -o public/index.css",
    "dev": "yarn install && yarn start",
    "start": "FAST_REFRESH=false CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true WDS_SOCKET_HOST=127.0.0.1 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "daisyui": "^3.9.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "postcss-cli": "^10.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

Here is my tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
}
```

Here is my index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.btn{
    text-transform: none;
}
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml (only the part of the react app):

```
  app:
    build:
      context: ./app
      target: dev
    # port 3000 needs to be exposed in development for React hot reloading (remove exposed ports for PROD)
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - $HOME/.yarn:/root/.yarn
    environment:
      - YARN_CACHE_FOLDER=/root/.yarn
    labels:
      traefik.http.routers.app.rule: Host(`localhost.devcom.vt.edu`)
#      traefik.http.services.app.loadbalancer.server.port: 3000
    depends_on:
      - api
```

Here is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import {RouteConstants} from "./shared/constants/RouteConstants";
import Home from "./components/Home/Home";
import About from "./components/Infos/About";
import Project from "./components/Project/Project";
import {ConfigContextProvider} from "./shared/config/ConfigContext";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./app/store";

const root = document.getElementById('root');

fetch("/config/config.json")
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(config => {
        ReactDOM.render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ConfigContextProvider config={config}>
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <App>
                            <Switch>
                                {/*<Route path={`${RouteConstants.jobsRoute}/:jobId`} component={ withAuth(JobDetail) }/>*/}
                                {/*<Route path={`${RouteConstants.myProjectsRoute}/:projectId`} component={ withAuth(ProjectDetail) }/>*/}
                                <Route path={RouteConstants.myProjectsRoute} component={Project}/>
                                <Route path={RouteConstants.aboutRoute} component={About}/>
                                <Route path={RouteConstants.homeRoute} component={Home}/>
                                <Redirect to={RouteConstants.homeRoute}/>
                            </Switch>
                        </App>
                    </BrowserRouter>
                </ConfigContextProvider>
            </Provider>,
            root
        );
    })
    .catch(() => {
        alert("No config.json file found");
    });
```

I tried deleting the node_modules and rerun it, but it still doesn't work